# Is it possible to return a reference property in an App Engine computed property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model, reference

I have a model with an attribute that is a reference to another model. The model it references depends on some logic. Is there a way to have a computed property that gives me the same ReferenceProperty niceties (reverse references, dereferencing)?

So far I the computed property stores a db.Key, but this is not optimal. Can I have a Computed 
Reference Property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you'd have to write your own custom Property subclass. You should be able to do so by examining the code behind `ComputedProperty` and `ReferenceProperty`; in effect you'd be combining the two.